# ¿ Como leer el atributo name al usar filepond?

Tags: javascript, php

Hola quiza un poco de orientacion estoy tratanto de usar este plugin https://pqina.nl/filepond/plugins/ (filepond)

Al momento de cargar la imagen y enviarlo por post simplemente el atributo name no se lee. Para eso eh estado probando con un echo y ver si la imagen se envia por el formulario pero nada solo recibo un `Warning: Undefined array key "img"`

El codigo usado para ellos es el mas simple:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
    $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    echo $img; //muestra warning
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond@^4/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="img">
        <input type="submit" name="subir" value="subir imagen">
    </form>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond@^4/dist/filepond.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Get a reference to the file input element
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

        // Create a FilePond instance
        const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Eh buscado informacion pero no encuentro solucion. ¿Algun consejo?

Comment: Y si pruebas con: const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {storeAsFile: true,});

Comment: muchas gracias era justo lo que me faltaba